# Android Application Lock

Tags: android

how to make application lock for android mobile.how to lock the application. I have done locking the home screen i.e the entire mobile, but im not sure how to lock particular application.

Comment: check https://github.com/amirarcane/lock-screen

Answer (score 1):

For this situation you need to catch the listener event to lock the installed apps..

Comment: Am doing the R&D in that...i'll give you the concept as soon as i get a flow in it

Comment: FYI, booting the phone into safe mode can get past this. Just sayin' :P

Comment: What was the code you used? I am tryna write an app to block certain apps for a specific amount of time. I have the packagenames I just need to figure out how to block

Comment: @RohitTigga, how can i lock app for specific amount of time when I have its package name.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I don't quite get what you're trying to di.

If you're trying to prevent people from using an app after it's downloaded the only way I can think of is having an HTTP(S) request done to a server with an identifier that is set the first time the app is run and check a DB to see if it can run (set a boolean flag `shouldRun` or something like it).

If you wat to prevent it from being copied from one phone to another, you can use the Google Play built in option to prevent it.

if this is what you're trying to achieve, you should probably obfuscate your code as well

**[obfuscating code on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation)**

Comment: I think what the OP is asking is "how do I lock an application from starting up". For example, by "locking the application", the OP means that when the user clicks the application from the launcher, a lock screen will be shown. The user can only use the application if the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support in the Android SDK to reliably do this. The application locking apps that are currently on the market aren't reliable in that they exploit a security loophole and put themselves in the foreground when you try to run a given application. This can be bypassed without much difficulty if you know how, and the security flaws they exploit will hopefully be closed. Sorry.

Comment: Sry friends what i mean that i read all the installed application and system application in android. Now i plan to Enable/Disable the application is it possible or in other way there is any term of setting permission for this. Anyother suggestion for this. Thank you in advance eagerly waiting for your response

Comment: There is no "secure" way to do this. You could write something that prevents the user from opening an application, but there would *always* a way to bypass it (unless you wrote your own firmware, which isn't exactly plausible). Android is designed explicitly to empower the person who holds the device. Enterprises and malware authors have the same objective: take control from the user and give that control to somebody else. Android defends users against malware authors, which limits enterprise flexibility. So, yes, it can be done... but it can be bypassed simply by booting into safe mode.